# How can I batch-download expiring links?

Tags: linux, download, wget

I have a few hundred files to download. The URLs are 'expiring' and are of the format:

```
https://website.com/directory/file1.iso?expires=xxxxxxx&token=yyyyyyy
```

`xxxxxxx` is the Unix epoch time. Each link is generated by viewing the page it is on.

I can download each one individually using Wget, but if I try to download several in a list, the links expire before the list is finished.

Is it possible using Wget or some other software, to generate each link right before it is downloaded, rather than have to put all of the URLs in a list at the start?